# React: Convert PDF to PNGs and upload the images to Cloudinary

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm working with react typescript and I want to choose a PDF file, convert the PDF into an image, and upload the result in Cloudinary. I already have a service that will upload images in my Cloudinary media library, but I don't know how to convert a pdf to images.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Be sure and research questions on your own before asking them here, we as a community can be a bit stingy when it comes to that sort of thing. A quick google search pops up https://github.com/mooz/node-pdf-image, a library that does exactly what you want.  Congratulations on asking your first question, and feel free to read through the FAQ and tour pages to get a better idea of how the site works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thx for the answer. I had searched, but when trying to implement some "solutions" using the pdfjs package, these did not give good results. Thanks for the link, I'll try this way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily convert the PDF to images using Cloudinary - 
Just upload the PDF as you would have done with photos, and use any transformation that you would like to generate any image format:

Example:
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/single_page_pdf.pdf

Transformation:
https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/f_png/w_500/e_make_transparent/e_replace_color:red:50:darkgray/b_yellow/bo_3px_solid_blue/single_page_pdf.pdf

Breakdown:

- `f_png` - Transforming to PNG
- `w_500` - Setting result image width to 500px
- `e_make_transparent` - Removing the white background
- `e_replace_color:red:50:darkgray` - Replacing the text color from dark gray to red
- `b_yellow` - Setting the background yellow
- `bo_3px_solid_blue` - Setting a solid blue border of 3px around the image

More transformations here:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformation_reference?query=e_replace_color&c_query=Image%20transformation%20reference#e_replace_color